# SailsJS Connections

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I built my code using SailsJS, and configured the connection to work with PostgreSQL. But on username and password fields, I want to retrieve this information from another function. Anyone knows how I can do this.

Example:

```js
pgDatabase: {
     adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
     host: 'server',
     port: port,
     user: getUsername(function(p) {
       return(p);
     }), // optional
     password: getPassword(function(c) {
       return(c);
     }), // optional
     database: 'db', //optional
     pool: false
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define username and password in your **config/env** file different for development and production and in connections you can access it as shown in below line of code

```
username: (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") ? "productionUser" : "otherUserName",
password: (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") ? "productionPassword" : "otherPassword";
```

NODE_ENV can be set while lifting sails

```
NODE_ENV=production sails lift
NODE_ENV=development sails lift
```

Comment: This is ok, but not what I need. I'm needing to get from a funcion, not from environment. Because I have another system to manage the user and password

Answer (score 0):

You can define username, password in your api/services methods. Depending upon your need either you can create multiple services or single service which will return required values.

```
module.exports = () => {
  return () => {

    return 'localhost';
    //return Promise.resolve(convertedObject);
  }
```

}

As per your requirement, Sailsjs bootstrap file is the best place to set database credentials.

> sails.config.bootstrap is a customizable, asynchronous bootstrap
>   function that runs before your Sails app gets lifted (i.e. starts up).

The code in bootstrap :

```
sails.config.connections.developmentServer.host = setDBCredentials()();
```

In the above "developmentServer" is the for MySQL adapter key.

```
developmentServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: '',
    user: 'root', //optional
    password: 'password', //optional
    database: 'bb' //optional
  }
```

Lift the app , it will set the host into your adapter

Answer (score 0):

mention it on Node_env file

```
username: (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") ? "productionUser" : "otherUserName",
password: (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") ? "productionPassword" : "otherPassword";
```

or create a js file on the app root path and export the config file, now on connection.js simply import the file and use it

```
export config
Ex: 
dbconfig.js
  const config =  (username, password) => {
           // Do your staff hear
           return username
           return password
}
export default config

import config
Ex:
connection.js
const dbConfig = require(../dbconfig.js)
const username = dbConfig.config , password = dbConfig.config
```